# Create a set of prime factor numbers given a set of tuples

Tags: syntax

Given a set $\Omega$ of tuples, for example,

```
Tuples[{Range[0, 4], Range[0, 3], Range[0, 2]}]
```

how can I create all numbers on the form $p_1^{t_1}p_2^{t_2}p_3^{t_3}$ where $p_i$ are (prime) numbers and $(t_1,t_2,t_3)\in\Omega$? (This will give all possible dividers of $p_1^4p_2^3p_3^2$.)

It could be done with a basic `For` loop and splitting the elements into parts etc. but there must be a shorter, better and (much) smarter way to do it. TIA.

Comment: Why not just use `Divisors[p1^4 * p2^3 * p3^2]` ?

Comment: `(Times @@ ({p1, p2, p3}^#)) & /@ Tuples[{Range[0, 4], Range[0, 3], Range[0, 2]}]`

Comment: #1. I did not know of this function. Thank you for solutions.